# SWIFT 3 - AVAudioPlayer - Possible to write a function to pass in sounds easily to an Audio Player?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avaudioplayer

I've not much experience with coding yet, I'm still very much a beginner, but I'm doing something where I'm sure there must be a more efficient way.

I've created an extremely simple app for my 2yr old daughter, where there is a screen with animal icons, each icon takes you to a new page where there is a picture of an animal. You press the animal, it makes the sound. Very simple.

The app is structured like this :

Homescreen with 15 icons, each with a Segue to a new storyboard that has a view controller associated with it (that's a subclass of viewController)

Each and every sound is declared as a variable, with a player in the primary viewController. Like so (2 examples)-->

```
    var lionSound:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    var cowSound:AVAudioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    let lionAudio = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sndLion", ofType: "wav")
            try lionSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: lionAudio!) as URL)

        let cowAudio = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sndCow", ofType: "wav")
            try cowSound = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: cowAudio!) as URL)
```

I am then creating an IBAction button in each individual animals viewController that plays the sound, like :

```
    lionSound.play()
    cowSound.play()
```

Now this question may appear incredibly stupid, but is there any way I can write a function where I can pass in the name/path of the sound, and the request to play it? I've done research here and other websites, but can't see what I'm looking for, which makes me think I might be wrong in my line of thinking.

From tutorials I've read, it's always been insisted that good code shouldn't repeat itself. Well I appear to be repeating myself a lot in this app, so is there a better way?

Sorry to ramble on... thanks for reading if you made it this far :) 
If any more information is needed, happy to provide it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Put all your audio files in folder directory (e.g yourAudioFileFolder). 
to create a folder in your app directory print(NSHomeDirectory()) and copy the log path and go to finder -> Go -> Go to Folder and paste the log path and press go. the return array will be the list of all filename of your audio.

```
func audioFileInArray() -> [String] {
    var audioFiles = [String]()
    let filemanager:FileManager = FileManager()
    let files = filemanager.enumerator(atPath: NSHomeDirectory()+"/yourAudioFileFolder")
    while let file = files?.nextObject() {
        audioFiles.append(file as! String)
    }
    return audioFiles
}

let yourAudioFiles = audioFileInArray()
print(yourAudioFiles)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to reply guys. I will have a play around tomorrow and let you know how it works out. Appreciate your time !

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of sound filenames (minus the extension). Create a method `playSound(index:Int)` Have that method create a sound player, use the index to fetch the filename, and use `url(forResource:withExtension:)` to get an `URL` to the file, and then create an audio player from that URL using `init(contentsOf:)`

You could even create an Int enum where each value is an index into your array of sound filenames, and make your playSound function take an enum instead of an int: `playSound(sound: SoundEnum)`. That would make your code more self-documenting.